# Django: after submitting the form, why the redirected url is an empty page

Tags: python, html, django

After submitting the form (input), it will redirect to another page(result).
The thing is it will indeed go to the desired url, but the content is empty. (It is not empty if I open it separately). Thanks for your suggestion in advance.

**input -- url**

```
from inputform import views
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from inputform.views import input
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^result_list/$',ResultView.as_view(),name='result'),
    (r'^input/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/result_list/')),
      }
```

**input --views**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response,get_object_or_404
from inputform.forms import Inputform
from inputform.models import Input
from dupont.models import Result
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

@csrf_exempt

def input(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Inputform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            print (cd['company'])
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse,('','result_list'))
```

**Result --views.py**

```js
class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    queryset = Result.objects.all()
 
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['input'] = Input.objects.all()
        return context
```

**Result -- html**

```
<form action="result_list/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="field" >
        <label> Select the Region:
        {{ form.regionlist }}
            {% for region in form.regionlist.choices %}
                 <option value="{{ val }}" {% ifequal data.val val %}selected {% endifequal %}></option>
            {% endfor %}
        </label>
    </div>

<div class="fieldWrapper"> 
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p></div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the correct parameter to pass to `reverse()` is 'result', i.e the name of the url.

If you're using django 1.7 or higher you can skip the reverse part and django will do it automatically for you.

```
def input(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Inputform(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        print (cd['company'])
        form.save()
        return redirect('result')
```

should work for you

Comment: note that the redirect shortcut handled the `reverse` long before 1.7!

Comment: Hi, I am using django 1.8, after changing the code as above, it is still redirect to an empty page, but for sure it is not empty page when opening separately. Is there any other reason?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code. Perhaps for some reason it is returning an empty HttpResponse

Comment: @Resley Rodrigues, Hi~I have uploaded code for result, the html is incomplete because it is too long I don't want to confuse people. thanks.

Comment: It can direct to the desired url, and then I have to press "Enter" to show the content. If I don't press "Enter", it will be just empty page. Is this normal?

Comment: Well I'm glad the problem is solved. Maybe those functions were needed somewhere.

Comment: The problem is solved finally, it is directing to empty page because there is some thing wrong in the code.